# How to get arbitrary return values in c++

Tags: c++, function, math, return-value, return-type

I am trying to write divisor function, Which gives all divisor of given number. But in that I do not want any array rather I want to return every divisors one by one. Is it possible?

This is code :

```
auto allDivisor(int num){
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
```

But I got only first iterations result:
`Enter integer number : 10 All divisior of 10 : 1`

Comment: C++ has no generators like Python does. It's not impossible to implement such a feature, but probably not worth it to go against the language.

Comment: You could write a functor that maintains internal state and uses that to power `operator()` calls or something, but really you probably want to step back and re-examine what you're trying to do overall that you think "a function that returns a sequence of values, one by one" is the solution to.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There is `co_yield` and upcoming `std::generator` that works quite similar to Python generator.

Comment: This kind of 'function' is known as a generator. Such a thing needs an internal state, in C++ that means writing a class. On that class you could overload the `()` operator that makes it seem syntactically like a function. Such objects are called *functors*. Anther choice would be to overload the `>>` operator, which in C++ terms makes it seem like you are 'reading' the divisors from the object. But any way you look at it you need know how to write classes and overload operators.

Comment: An option is do it with a pair of functions that use static data to communicate.  One function does setup.  The other is called repeatedly (e.g. in a loop) and checks/updates the static data, in order to return the next value needed.    This approach needs the function called in the loop to provide some indication to the caller when done.    Overall though, you'd be better off rethinking your requirement.    To have a function that returns a different value on each call requires some bookkeeping that makes it more complicated and error-prone (both to implement the function, and to call it).

Answer (score 0):

the usual way is to call your function multiple times and each time it will return different divisor until the end is marked by some special return value like `0` ... the iteration can be done either by passing `i` as function parameter or have it as global or static variable but that would make your function thread unsafe prohibiting to use it in parallel (even in serial overlapped with other division) ... It would look like this:

```cpp
int allDivisor(int num)
    {
    static int i=0;
    for (i++;i<=num;i++)
    if ((num%i)==0) return i;
    if (i>num){ i=0; return 0; }
    }
```

and usage:

```cpp
int d,X;
for (X=32;;)
    {
    d=allDivisor(X);
    if (!d) break;
    cout << d;
    }
for (X=125;;)
    {
    d=allDivisor(X);
    if (!d) break;
    cout << d;
    }
```

outputting this:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
1
5
25
125
```

however be sure you always call the `allDivisor` until it returns `0` otherwise its next usage would be messedup (skipped first divisors until last `i` state) ... that could be repaired too for example like this (at cost of another static variable):

```
int allDivisor(int num)
    {
    static int i=0,n=0;
    if (n!=num){ n=num; i=0; }
    for (i++;i<=num;i++)
    if ((num%i)==0) return i;
    if (i>num){ i=0; n=0; return 0; }
    }
```